# Is it OK to loop over recv / read to read all data from socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm building a multi-client<->server messaging application over TCP.
I created a non blocking server using epoll to multiplex linux file descriptors.
When a fd receives data, I read() /or/ recv() into buf.
I know that I need to either specify a data length* at the start of the transmission, or use a delimiter** at the end of the transmission to segregate the messages.

*using a data length:

```
char *buffer_ptr = buffer;
        do {
            switch (recvd_bytes = recv(new_socket, buffer_ptr, rem_bytes, 0)) {
                  case -1: return SOCKET_ERR;
                  case 0: return CLOSE_SOCKET;
                  default: break;
            }
            buffer_ptr += recvd_bytes;
            rem_bytes -= recvd_bytes;
        } while (rem_bytes != 0);
```

**using a delimiter:

```
void get_all_buf(int sock, std::string & inStr)
{
    int n = 1, total = 0, found = 0;
    char c;
    char temp[1024*1024]; 
    // Keep reading up to a '\n'
    while (!found) {
        n = recv(sock, &temp[total], sizeof(temp) - total - 1, 0);
        if (n == -1) {
            /* Error, check 'errno' for more details */
            break;
        }
        total += n;
        temp[total] = '\0';
        found = (strchr(temp, '\n') != 0);
    }
    inStr = temp;
}
```

My question: Is it OK to loop over recv() until one of those conditions is met? What if a client sends a bogus message length or no delimiter or there is packet loss? Wont I be stuck looping recv() in my program forever?

Comment: Welcome to the joys of protocol design.  Your choices are wait forever (like NFS3 does) or timeout (like http does).

Comment: this is a low latency application - receiving thousands of msgs per second

Comment: was thinking to maybe call recv a couple more times then close the connection if nothing else was on the fd

Comment: Consider using a per-connection buffer with an incoming message size limit. You can see something similar in the [facil.io](http://facil.io) WebSocket implementation (a dynamic message size limit) or it's HTTP implementation (a hard-coded header line length limitation).

Comment: P.S. (Side Note): Using `epoll` in one-shot mode might be better than edge triggering if you're using multiple threads, since it could minimize lock contention (and avoid some locks altogether, depending on your design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it OK to loop over recv() until one of those conditions is met?

Probably not, at least not for production-quality code.  As you suggested, the problem with looping until you get the full message is that it leaves your thread at the mercy of the client -- if a client decides to only send part of the message and then wait for a long time (or even forever) without sending the last part, then your thread will be blocked (or looping) indefinitely and unable to serve any other purpose -- usually not what you want.

> What if a client sends a bogus message length

Then you're in trouble (although if you've chosen a maximum-message-size you can detect obviously bogus message-lengths that are larger than that size, and defend yourself by e.g. forcibly closing the connection)

> or there is packet loss?

If there is a reasonably small amount of packet loss, the TCP layer will automatically retransmit the data, so your program won't notice the difference (other than the message officially "arriving" a bit later than it otherwise would have).  If there is really bad packet loss (e.g. someone pulled the Ethernet cable out of the wall for 5 minutes), then the rest of the message might be delayed for several minutes or more (until connectivity recovers, or the TCP layer gives up and closes the TCP connection), trapping your thread in the loop.

So what is the industrial-grade, evil-client-and-awful-network-proof solution to this dilemma, so that your server can remain responsive to other clients even when a particular client is not behaving itself?

The answer is this:  don't depend on receiving the entire message all at once.  Instead, you need to set up a simple state-machine for each client, such that you can `recv()` as many (or as few) bytes from that client's TCP socket as it cares to send to you at any particular time, and save those bytes to a local (per-client) buffer that is associated with that client, and then go back to your normal event loop even though you haven't received the entire message yet.  Keep careful track of how many valid received-bytes-of-data you currently have on-hand from each client, and after each recv() call has returned, check to see if the associated per-client incoming-data-buffer contains an entire message yet, or not -- if it does, parse the message, act on it, then remove it from the buffer.  Lather, rinse, and repeat.